# Can you develop algorithms to predict synthesis of peptides?

Tags: synthesis

This may be a very foolish question, but do (complex) algorithms exist to predict the steps and materials involved (or therefore different options and paths) in synthesis for the given input of for example a target molecular structure or formula? In this case for example peptides, so potentially larger molecules. But the question applies generally i guess.

If that makes sense, meaning there is a large amount of known patterns which overlap for a wide array of target at least in partial which can be applied or reverse calculated based on structure and known properties, i'm sure such things would be already available as products for the research, chemical or pharma industry.

Is there any public work for that thats mature, does it not exist to a large extend or is only available as very niche industry products?

Comment: This is a subject of considerable interest and effort in current research. There is a large article on Computer-guided retrosynthesis in the most recent issue of Chemistry in Britian. Have a look here: https://askcos.mit.edu/  and here  https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-020-00472-1

Comment: @Waylander Interesting, i had a feeling stuff likethis must either exist or being worked on already... i dont understand the full complexicity of chemical synthesis but i feel like it would be stupid if that wasnt the case. Thanks for providing these links!

Comment: "This may be a very foolish question" question wouldn't be bad if not for the example - peptides are pretty much strings of monomers - just a look at it should be enough to know how to make them (if you know general method) - there's nothing to "predict". Just adding one aminoacid after another.